# Google Maps v3 has stopped displaying tiles

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've been developing a mapping/search app for several months (unfortunately can't share URL) and the Google Maps portion has worked fine the entire time.

I have an instance of this app on a *beta* server that hasn't been modified at all in over a month.  I say that up front, just to be clear that *I have not introduced a bug*...  something has to have changed on Google's end.

Up until Valentine's Day weekend, everything worked fine. Upon returning to work after the weekend, the map no longer displays tiles. Markers and pins still show up, and everything can be dragged, so the script *is* working, and I can see the tiles are requested successfully but they are no longer being assigned as background images to the DIVs.

This behavior happens in Chrome and Firefox.  Interestingly, everything still works in Safari.

The map is instantiated dynamically in a React app, in case that info helps.

Obviously this isn't a universal problem or else everyone would be complaining about it.  But without a doubt, Google has changed *something* in the way the Maps API v3 applies tiles, and this has broken my app.

Worst of all, I can't find any announcements or release notes for any changes made this week, so I have no idea where to even start.

Comment: There was an update of the API recently.  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Is there somewhere online where I can see an announcement or release notes for the update?

Comment: In the documentation.  [Release notes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/releases).  From the latest post on [google-maps-js-api-v3-notify group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-maps-js-api-v3-notify) (referenced in the release notes): "The new release will be made live on or shortly after February 16 2016!"

Answer (score 0):

I stripped everything out of my app until I found a cause.

The problem turned out to be something in Bootstrap...

```js
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 1,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.409532, -2.010498)
}

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
```

```css
/* this offending code was in my Bootstrap */

img { max-width:100% !important }
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&.js"></script>
<div id="map" style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%"></div>
```

I'm really curious what kind of change was made in order for that to have worked before but be failing now. I'd also like to understand how that's breaking my app in development, but not breaking our legacy app which also has that rule in place.

Comment: That has always been an issue with the Google Maps API v3 and bootstrap [SO search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-maps-api-3%5D+img+%7B+max-width%3A100%25+%7D)

Comment: Interesting.  Add it to the list of reasons I hate Bootstrap. Thanks for all your help/feedback!